# codeigniter error in page source view

Tags: codeigniter

I'm working with one array that have 55 elements inside and each one are another array with 17 elements each one.

When I show the array on the screen, nothing wrong happens but when I take a look in the page source, I have 55 x 17 **"Severity: Notice"** errors with the message **"Undefined index"**.
Does someone know what can be wrong?

If the index really doesn't exist, I couldn't see the array on the screen.

I tested using `if ( isset( ) ) { ... }`, but still the same.

Codeigniter version: 1.7.2
Browsers tested: firefox, chrome, ie and safari.

Answer (score 1):

I usually get this errors when I'm trying to echo something that is not defined. It's not an PHP error, only a notice. This is produced by the function **error_reporting();** on the main index.php.

If you open this index.php file, you will see:

```
/*
|---------------------------------------------------------------
| PHP ERROR REPORTING LEVEL
|---------------------------------------------------------------
|
| By default CI runs with error reporting set to ALL.  For security
| reasons you are encouraged to change this when your site goes live.
| For more info visit:  http://www.php.net/error_reporting
|
*/
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

You've two options:

1. Don't print a variable that is not defined.
2. Change the error_reporting(); with a non-notice prints. Like: `error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);`.

Wish this helps you!

Comment: Thanks but still the same. Now I have another message in the page source, after I upload a file. The message says "You did not select a file to upload", but the file was uploaded.

Comment: Try, instead of isset(), if(isset($var) AND $var != NULL) { }

Comment: It is better to use empty(); it returns true if the variable is undefined, or if it is an empty array, or if it is false or null or 0. So !empty($var) is what I'm really trying to determine.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with CI or your browser, it is a classic PHP notice.

Comment: As the answer below mine suggests, you can output PHP warnings, notices, etc. These notices will indicate the line number in your code where the notice originated from. That allows you spot the problem, most likely it is indeed the case of using an index that does not exist.